# Ultra web Grid columns in Infragistics and user controls

Tags: user-controls, infragistics

My user control(.Net) uses a ultrawebgrid and I want to pass the value of one of the column to another column in the same grid ..can any one suggest me the best way to pass the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose those columns as public properties of the user control (GET/SET). This way you will be able to operate them outside of the control itself.